# Sending an object with request

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

In the below code i am trying to send a object with the request,Is this correct if so how to decode it in template

```
 def index(request):
      cat = Category.objects.filter(title="ASD")
      dict = {'cat' : cat}
       request.update('dict' : dict) 
          #or
       request.dict=dict;
```

And In the templates can we write the code as

```
     {% for obj in request.dict%}
          obj.title
     {% endfor %}
```

`EDIT:`
          If i am calling function like

```
      def post_list(request, page=0, paginate_by=20, **kwargs):
        logging.debug("post_list")
        page_size = getattr(settings,'BLOG_PAGESIZE', paginate_by)
        return list_detail.object_list(
        request,
        queryset=Post.objects.published(),
        paginate_by=page_size,
        page=page,
        **kwargs
      )
```

Comment: Have you done the official tutorial? It looks like you're missing a few basic concepts here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, but why would you want to? Django has a simple, well-defined and well-documented way of passing data into templates - through the context. Why try and find ways to work around that?

**Edit after comment** No. Again, Django has a perfectly good way of passing extra context into a generic view, via the `extra_context` parameter which again [is well-documented](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-list-detail-object-list).

Comment: I had asked this question because i am passing few parameters to djangos list_detail.object_list() and so i had to pass it like this.Can u please let me know what is the correct way to pass through the request.Thanks....

Comment: Please see the edit,if i am calling the function as shown in the edit how can i pass extra_context??

Comment: Did you try adding `extra_context` to the list of arguments to `object_list`?

Comment: return list_detail.object_list(
        request,
        queryset=Post.objects.published(),
        paginate_by=page_size,
        page=page,extra_context={'sumvar': sumvar},
        **kwargs
      )
    Will this work

Comment: I made the comment because the variable could not be printed from the template

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing the actual function you use to render your view ([`render()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), [`render_to_response()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response), etc.).

Let's say you are using [`render_to_response()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) :

```
render_to_response(template_name[, dictionary][, context_instance][, mimetype])
```

> Renders a given template with a given
>   context dictionary and returns an
>   HttpResponse object with that rendered
>   text.

So if you pass in `{"foo": your_object}` as a dictionary you can use `{{ foo }}` directly in your template.

---

If you are using the [`object_list`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-list-detail-object-list) generic view you should use the `extra_context`:

> extra_context: A dictionary of values
>   to add to the template context. By
>   default, this is an empty dictionary.
>   If a value in the dictionary is
>   callable, the generic view will call
>   it just before rendering the template.